# How is the input_matrix * weight_matrix + bias_vector possible in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra

Given an `N x M` input matrix `X`, an `M x U` weight matrix `W`, and a bias vector `b` of length U,
how is the affine transformation XW + b possible? If the result `R` of the matrix multiplication is of shape `N x U`, how is the bias vector `b` added to to `R`? I have tried googling matrix-vector addition but have only found results for matrix-matrix or vector-vector addition. Based on the [Matrix Addition Wiki Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition), this transformation shouldn't be possible, but clearly I misunderstand something.

Example code below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Define tensors
N = 10
M = 4
input_matrix = tf.random.normal(shape=(N, M))

U = 2 
weight_matrix = tf.random.normal(shape=(M, U))
bias_vector = tf.random.normal(shape=(U,))

# Affine transformation
R = tf.matmul(input_matrix, weight_matrix) + bias_vector
print(input_matrix.shape, '*', weight_matrix.shape, '+', bias_vector.shape, '=', R.shape)
>>> (10, 4) * (4, 2) + (2,) = (10, 2)
```

Comment: The bias is being broadcast to each training example. More info about broadcasting: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: This makes sense, but doesn't this mean that the operation is not matrix + vector but rather matrix + matrix? Since the bias vector has its dimensions extended (broadcast) to the dimensions matching the left operand, then the operation that is actually occurring is R_(10, 2) + b_(10, 2)? Also, since is the case, why would documentation like the [Keras Dense Layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/) and other textbooks write the transformation as XW + b if such an operation is not actually defined without broadcasting?

Comment: They're playing fast and loose with notation. The simplest way to think about a dense layer is a vector representing a single training example, multiplied by the weight matrix, plus the bias vector. You can stack multiple input vectors into a matrix. Multiplying by an input matrix instead of an input vector and broadcasting the bias accomplishes the same thing, but for multiple inputs. The reason why you'd prefer multiplying a matrix by a matrix, rather than repeatedly multiplying a vector times a matrix is that there are fast algorithms for matrix multiplication.

Comment: @NickODell What is odd to me though is that a foundational operation of neural nets is represented with an operation that is undefined (i.e., Matrix + Vector). I haven't really thought about the operation itself until recently (I have built several custom architectures for variational autoencoders, rnns for time series forecasting, so I have a lot of 'practical' experience). It is just disconcerting that broadcasting *must* occur and is not mentioned (at least I don't see it mentioned in books like [Deep Learning](https://itnext.io/creating-a-tensorflow-dnn-in-c-part-1-54ce69bbd586)).